# the verb "Arrive" with no preposition

Tags: prepositions

I've found an interesting sentence and I'm trying to figure out whether it is correct or not.

The sentence is:

> When we arrived the forest, it was getting darker.

As far as I know, it is not allowed to use the verb without a preposition.

So, it should be

> When we arrived **in** the forest, it was getting darker.

shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, 'arrive' should take a preposition in this case. I recall that "when we arrived home", for instance, requires no preposition, but in your case it definitely is necessary.

Comment: "when we arrived home" is an implied version of "when we arrived (at) home".

Comment: The example of *arriving home* is an interesting one. In short, *home* acts like a prepositional phrase instead of a noun in some contexts. For example, *"Honey, I'm home!"* means "I am **at** home" not "I am **a** home".

Comment: I saw a sentence with "arrived home" ,but it is rather clear that the noun "home" doesn't require a preposition

Comment: @Era Home doesn't act like a prepositional phrase. It is an adverb like there and here. I arrived there. I arrived here. You don't need to place a preposition before an adverb.

Comment: @Rathony Those are all adverbs that function like prepositional phrases. You can replace them with prepositional phrases and they mean the same thing. (e.g. "here" = "at this location".) Unlike most other adverbs, they describe *where* you arrived, not *how* you arrived. That's all I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the dictionary definitions, [arrive](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/arrive) is an intransitive verb. So it cannot have a direct object. Therefore:

> When we arrived the forest, it was getting darker.

is incorrect (*forest* would be a direct object here).

> When we arrived **in the forest**, it was getting darker.

Is correct. But the prepositional phrase is not required, as in:

> When we arrived, it was getting darker.